# Insert row with auto increment

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

I create this table

```
CREATE TABLE table_test(
   id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
   varchar,
  description varchar
);
```

And I was expecting that since id was uuid, it would be auto incremented automatically

```
INSERT INTO table_test (title,description) VALUES ('a','B');
```

It throw error

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Some partition key parts are missing: id
  com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Some partition key parts are missing: id
```

Any idea what I´m doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use now() function**

> In the coordinator node, generates a new unique timeuuid in milliseconds when the statement is executed. The timestamp portion of the timeuuid conforms to the UTC (Universal Time) standard. This method is useful for inserting values. The value returned by now() is guaranteed to be unique.

**There is no auto increment option in Cassandra.**

now() function return a timeuuid, it is not auto increment.  It has two bigint part MSB and LSB. MSB is the current timestamp and LSB is the combination of clock sequence and node ip of the host. And **It is universal unique**.

Use the below query to insert :

```
INSERT INTO table_test (id,title,description) VALUES (now(),'a','B');
```

Source : http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html

Comment: But If I have to pass the now, how come it´s type uuid?, it´s just a varchar where I have to pass the uuid

Comment: `now()` is a function of cassandra, now() return a timeuuid

Comment: Yeah ok, but what I mean is that in others data bases as MySQL you put a column as auto increment and automatically he start adding 1,2,3 n once you add a row.

Comment: **There is no auto increment option in Cassandra.** like mysql